# How can I get all Id in array of object by using foreach and merge the all data corresponding ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

> I am working on typescript api i merged all the data with this api i
> am getting some data from another api function merged with this api, I
> will give my some code only data adding first index of array. I need
> to "Communes" and "Category" and "Location" data add all issuer_id
> this data i will show below.
>
> This code i am using here for merge data.

```
 let premiumValue = (Object.values(values))
        console.log(premiumValue)      
    const issuerId = Object.values(premiumValue)[0].issuer_id
          const Communes = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'Communes')
         const category = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'company_type')     
         const location = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'location')    
       Object.assign(values[issuerId], { Communes }, { category }, { location })
       return Object.values(values)
```

> I am getting this kind of result:

```
[
    {
        "issuer_id": 64,
        "company_name": "Gastro Südtirol",
        "Total_Job": 2,
        "Communes": [],
        "category": [],
        "location": [
            {
                "id": 907,
                "location": "brixen"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 70,
        "company_youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB2bOahchY6Hsc_WXnQ-NCw",
        "company_name": "Auto Hofer",
        "Total_Job": 2
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 72,
        "company_name": "Assimeran GmbH",
        "Total_Job": 2
    }
 ]
```

> I need "Communes" and "Category" and "Location" data add all the array
> of json. only it is come first index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all Ids from your array of objects you should only loop and get issuer_id property on each object.

```
    const ids = []
    yourObject.forEach(({issuer_id}) => ids.push(issuer_id) )
  //opt2   const ids_2 = yourObject.map(({issuer_id}) => issuer_id)
```

I am not sure of what you want by "merging the all data to corresponding id"

maybe something like this ?

```
const hashList = {}
yourObject.forEach( ({issuer_id, ...restParams}) =>{ hashList[issuer_id] = restParams})
```

now you can access the id you want as easy as `hashList[idYouWant]`
Sorry for my identing, hope this is helpful in any way

Comment: Hi JulenAtWork, you can see this line Object.assign(values[issuerId], { Communes }, { category }, { location }) here i added communes and category and  location data also but i am getting this kind of data only first array of index i need all the array of index this kind of data need to be add.

Comment: I see, for your approach i think you should look   [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of ) for await of [link].

Comment: Hi JulenAtWork ,I edited my comment see my comment. i have explained

Comment: look at the documentation i linked. that might help you, since you need to add asynchronous data to your array